# Which fixings will hold a boxing bag from garage joist

Tags: garage, joists, hanging

I fitted a 5ft punch bag to a joist in my garage. I used the rawl plugs and screw provided. I drilled 6cm deep by 1cm diameter. Bashed the plugs in and  tightened the fixing. The bag stayed up for 15 minutes and then fell. The plugs and screws came out. The bag has approximately 50kg weight in it. On top of the joists there is board (loft flooring).

Another buyer made the same complaint so I was expecting it.

My question is which rawl plugs can I buy to make sure that it stays up. I have looked on various websites but I have been unable to deduce which plug will work best.

The *fixing*:
[image]

The joist from which the fixing fell:
[image]

The joist from a perpendicular angle (for context):
[image]

Comment: People on this stack love photos. because it helps them understand.  For myself there is the prurient joy of looking at things that have failed.  Please add images of the bag, where you want it and the plug and screws that came out.

Comment: I am glad the thing that falls down is the bag, not the joist. What kind of joist, size, and location of hanging (in the mid-span or near the end)? Also, can't find any information on "Raul Plugs", please show a picture of it.

Comment: I like the term “Fixings”. It’s not a construction term, but implies a “recipe” for the manner in which the pieces go together.

Comment: Apologies for taking soo long to add photographs. You can see the relevant parts and also the joists from 2 angles.

Comment: See how those rawl plugs are nice and smooth on the outside? There is **no way** those are going to hold up the weight of a punching bag for more than a few minutes or more than one punch. You _never_ use plugs when attaching things to wood. You only use them when attaching to drywall, plaster, brick, block or concrete - things that a screw cannot cut threads into, or are too weak for the threads to hold once cut. Good thing this is a nice cheap lesson for you with nothing broken and nobody injured - welcome to "learning through experience"!

Comment: It looks like you are using 2x4s as "joists" to support a floor.  Now you're drilling holes in them and then beating them with a punching bag.  Hopefully not while somebody walks around on top.   The simple answer to your question is to use wood screws without plugs to screw into wood, but I think you need someone with construction experience to come advise you on your whole setup.  You probably need to use stronger materials for *any* of the purposes you have there.

Comment: Got it, no plugs for wood. Makes perfect sense. @FreeMan

Comment: Do you mean 2x4 inches? Are they not joists? All we did was add floor boards for storing bits and pieces and there are also blocks of wood travelling perpendicular to the joists to add support. @jay613

Comment: @jay613 you're right, they do look like 2x4s. That wouldn't be unexpected if they were manufactured trusses. Trusses can be designed with areas for storage, so just because it's a 2x4 doesn't mean it's not strong enough. Can't tell from these pictures. Those 2 large holes straight up into the joist, however, will have significantly weakened it. The extra blocking on each side, if sufficiently attached, will help immensely.

Comment: Ok, let's proceed on the assumption that this is a truss ceiling, and that the "loft" is not for walking but only for tossing up some lightweight objects for storage.  In that case I like the accepted answer: block across two members and attach to the blocking.  Not sure how to repair drilled trusses.  I believe the impacted members are under tension so filling the holes won't help.

Comment: **Cease and desist.** What are we looking at? Upper shelving in a garage made out of 2x4s? **That's not something I'd be hanging anything off of**, let alone a non static load. If you're gonna anyway, drill holes laterally (not vertically) and use through bolts, nuts, and washers. And more chain or carabiners if you have to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend spanning two joists with a perpendicular member then attaching the bag to that crossmember with heavy wood screws. This spreads out the load on the joists. I don't like to drill large holes into the edge of a 2x4" joist, then putting a point load on a screw into that edge.

EDIT

Forty years ago I installed some very heavy ceiling fans in our house which has 2x4" ceiling joists on 24" centers. I inserted a 22.5" piece of 2x4 between two joists and attached it to the sides of the joists with Simpson Strong Tie metal corner brackets. I used the Simpson screws so as not to damage the ceiling drywall by nailing.

The heavy Hunter fan required drilling a single rather large hole (maybe 5/16" or larger) and screwing in a single heavy hook into the hole. I also used thread lubricant on the threads of the hook.

EDIT2

Given the low cost of the metal corner brackets you should use a total of four, two on each end.

Comment: That makes sense. I realise my mistake now. I have weakened the joist at that point. Perhaps I should fill those holes and/or add a brace either side to support it.

Comment: @fpsdkfsdkmsdfsdfm a hardwood dowel glued into the hole is a good start - it will prevent the wood of the joist from compressing there, allowing for a failure. Additionally, properly nailing more 2x material on one or both sides will definitely help. I'd suggest asking a _new_ question about how to do the repair work, though.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you putting rawl plugs into wood? They are meant for concrete and brick, unless your joist is not wood.

For wood, given you now have some holes that are enlarged, I would drill through and fit bolts with large washers to spread the load, even consider using a hardwood block each side to help perhaps glued to the joist face.

[image]

Comment: There are loft floor boards directly on top of the joists. Will this approach still work?

Comment: @fpsdkfsdkmsdfsdfm yes, as I stated - now given you a diagram to show the bolt going from one joist face to the other...

Answer (score 1):

As the fixings are going into a wood joist, the best choice would be long wood screws as they can be used without the need for wall plugs. The boxing bag bracket shown in the image below was mounted with this method, and it's been holding fine for several years.
[image]

To get a strong hold, you need to make sure the screws are located away from the existing holes you have drilled in the joist. To make the hold even stronger, you can also try adding a [strong adhesive](https://adiseal.com/adhesive-sealant/) between the metal bracket and the wood.

Comment: I appreciate the additional information I will combine this with the accepted answer.